# How I can create div only for mobile version?

Tags: html, css

I want to create div in html with images and texx, but It should appears only on mobile version, how i can make this ?
Here is some code.

```css
  /*-- Mobile Design---- */

@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 767px) {
  /* put your css styles in here */
  html,
  body {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
  a.navbar-brand img {
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 95%;
    max-width: 200px;
  }
  .header {
    height: 15%;
  }
  .navbar-toggler i {
    font-size: 22px;
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Hide the element by default and only show it when it fits your contraints. For example:

```
.yourElement {
   display: none;
}

@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 767px) {
   .yourElement {
       display: block;
    }
}
```